# Ajax POST results show empty values - ACF

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've created an AJAX function to "Show More" custom post types when the user clicks the corresponding button. The function works and populated the page but returns empty values/elements. I am currently using ACF and attempting to store the data in variables to be used in my functions.php, but unfortunately to no success. Any thoughts?

**Initial Script Enqueue function**

```
function synchrony_theme_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script('main-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array('jquery'), '', true);

  wp_localize_script('main-js', 'team_ajax', array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
  ));
}
```

**Jquery AJAX Function**

```
var count = 0;

function load_more_team(count) {

    var button = $('#more_posts'),
        count = count + 12,
        data =  {
            'action': 'ajax_more_team',
            'offset': count 
        }

    $.ajax({
        url: team_ajax.ajaxurl,
        data: data,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data){
            if(data.length){
                $("#ajax_posts").append(data);
                button.attr("disabled",false);
            } else{
                button.attr("disabled",true);
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
}

$('#more_posts').click(function() {
    $("#more_posts").attr("disabled",true);
    load_more_team();
});
```

**AJAX Handler in Functions.php**

```
function ajax_more_team($offset) {

$offset = $offset + 12;

header("Content-Type: text/html");

$args = array(
    'post_type' =>  'team',
    'posts_per_page'    =>  12,
    'offset'    =>  $offset
);

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);

$id = get_the_id(); 
$headshot = the_field('employee_headshot');
$name = the_field('employee_name');
$title = the_field('employee_title');
$company = the_field('employee_company');
$url = get_template_directory_uri();

$out = '';
    if ($the_query -> have_posts()) :  while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post();
        $id = get_the_id(); 
        $name = the_field('employee_name');

        $out .= '<div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 mb-4">
                    <div class="team-member">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#'.$id.'">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="'.$headshot.'" alt="'.$headshot.'">
                        </a>
                        <div class="team-info">
                            <h6>'.$name.'</h6>
                        </div>
                        <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                            <div class="modal-icon">
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="'.$url.'/imgs/modal-icon.svg">
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="'.$id.'" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="team-close-btn">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <img class="img-fluid" src="'.$headshot.'" alt="Alice George">
                                    <div class="team-info">
                                        <h6>'.$name.'</h6>
                                        <p><strong>Title:<br></strong>'.$title.'</p>
                                        <p><strong>Company:<br></strong>'.$company.'</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>';
        endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    die($out);
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_more_team', 'ajax_more_team');
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_more_team', 'ajax_more_team');

?>
```

I added the $id and $name vars in the loop to test if the data is pulled and it populates, just does not include in the desired areas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `the_field()` is like writing `echo $field` so it's only useful for displaying the data inline: `<h6><?php the_field('employee_name') ?></h6>`

To assign those fields to a variable and use them to build a larger string, you'll want to use `get_field('employee_name')` instead and you'll probably need to pass the id of the employee as the second parameter like `get_field('employee_name', $employee_id=100)`

Comment: I see, I looked more into your response on the `get_field()`. Saw that I could pass and false parameter to get the current post ID.  I also realized that I had the variable outside the loop. Once I placed the variables within my loop using the appropriate function, it populated as desired.

Comment: Also read up on some helpful doc: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/ and https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.